# Ignore certain changes in Ediff

Tags: ediff, diff

I have two versions of a file (or buffer) and I'm running ediff to compare them. Some of the changes are irrelevant and I want to ignore them. Specifically, `foo` has been renamed to `bar` in places and I don't care about that. Note that both versions have both `foo`s and `bar`s, just in different mixes.

How can I ignore regions where `foo` → `bar` is the only change? Either with Ediff itself, or with a third-party package, or with an external `diff` replacement that's easily available on Linux.

If `foo+corge` has changed to `bar+baz`, I *do* want to know about the change from `corge` to `baz` (whereas a change from `foo+corge` to `bar+corge` should be ignored). So I don't think that [selective browsing](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ediff/Selective-Browsing.html) (`#h`) can help me. What I really want to ignore is changes, not regions — though if a region has non-ignored changes, I don't mind if the refinement also highlights the ignored change.

Comment: Good question. I don't think there is a way, but if there is I too would like to know it. If not, consider logging an enhancement request...